# How to build a PyTorch model with RGCNConv or RGATConv operators for a HeteroData object from PyTorch Geometric?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, pytorch-geometric, gnn

I am using the [Relato business graph](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/thedevastator/relato-business-network-graph-373663-domain-conn) dataset, which I've converted (I believe successfully) to a HeteroData object, the structure of which is as follows:

```
{'Company': {'x': array([[17427,    38],
         [14258,    38],
         [ 1406,    38],
         ...,
         [38747,    38],
         [52844,    38],
         [ 3941,    38]])},
 ('Company',
  'Partnership',
  'Company'): {'edge_index': array([[17427, 17427, 17427, ..., 18679, 18679, 18679],
         [14258,  1406, 48890, ..., 46249, 29151, 11893]])},
 ('Company',
  'Customer',
  'Company'): {'edge_index': array([[33003, 33003, 33003, ..., 31860,  3498, 18679],
         [11076, 28905, 30047, ..., 35301, 31860,  3498]])},
 ('Company',
  'Investment',
  'Company'): {'edge_index': array([[ 2169,  1576, 12945, ..., 18679, 18679, 18679],
         [49750, 15248, 22702, ..., 29754, 24540, 25874]])},
 ('Company',
  'Competitor',
  'Company'): {'edge_index': array([[14476, 19356, 19356, ...,  7175,  7175,  7175],
         [14477, 46763,  7118, ..., 31706, 43920, 28769]])},
 ('Company',
  'Unknown',
  'Company'): {'edge_index': array([[52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875,
          52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875,
          52875, 52875, 52875, 52875],
         [52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875,
          52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875,
          52875, 52875, 52875, 52875]])},
 ('Company',
  'Supplier',
  'Company'): {'edge_index': array([[52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875,
          52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875,
          52875, 52875, 52875, 52875],
         [52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875,
          52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875, 52875,
          52875, 52875, 52875, 52875]])}}
```

So, there is one node type, 5 edge types, and one additional node feature being the type of domain of the website of each company. What I need to do is build a neural network with RGCNConv and RGATConv layers (those two specifically, and one separate model with each), for the following two purposes: community detection/clustering, and link prediction.

So, here is where I'm stuck as I don't know how to build the network itself. I don't know what the input dimension should be (maybe 2 as the node feature matrix has 2 attributes, the company and its domain type?), I don't know how to adapt the model for each of the two tasks that need to be done etc. I've gone through a bunch of examples in the [documentation](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/heterogeneous.html) and elsewhere but they're confusing and hard to understand as they're using them on preloaded graphs in PyTorch Geometric, or using  attributes that a HeteroData object doesn't have - like a unified edge_index since there is a separate edge index matrix provided for every permutation of node type - edge type - node type triplet, and there isn't one containing all edges, there are arguments in the forward function that I don't understand what they are and where they come from since they aren't passed to the model as arguments and they aren't attributes or methods of the class either.

I tried a lot of different examples online, from the documentation and from tutorials, and couldn't get anything close to working. In terms of community detection in particular I find it super hard to find any examples in code anywhere.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.